# Why does FocusOnKeyCallback return bool?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the dartdoc & declaration of `FocusOnKeyCallback`:

```
/// Signature of a callback used by [Focus.onKey] and [FocusScope.onKey]
/// to receive key events.
///
/// The [node] is the node that received the event.
typedef FocusOnKeyCallback = bool Function(FocusNode node, RawKeyEvent event);
```

The callback has a return type of bool, but how that value will be used is not clear. Would `void` have worked here?

*(originally asked on Flutter's GitHub: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45367)*

Answer (score 1):

It returns bool to mark that the event was handled by any of focus nodes, and if it wasn't, it calls the assert. Take a look at `_handleRawKeyEvent` method of `FocusManager` class:

```dart
    ...

    bool handled = false;
    for (FocusNode node in <FocusNode>[_primaryFocus, ..._primaryFocus.ancestors]) {
      if (node.onKey != null && node.onKey(node, event)) {
        assert(_focusDebug('Node $node handled key event $event.'));
        handled = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!handled) {
      assert(_focusDebug('Key event not handled by anyone: $event.'));
    }

    ...
```

So basically it's to prevent onKey event propagation.